# Is there a method to restrict going back in selected views?

Tags: javascript, django

I have a question,
Adding or inserting an X record redirects me to another page, all good so far. But in Chrome I can go back with the <- button, which makes it difficult for me, because I can make infinite records with different clear IDs, now my question is:
How not to regress in different points of view?
It is good to go back, but not in the views of: insert, update or delete. There is a Javascript method for Chrome, but it didn't work very well for me. Is there a method?
[Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eHi2aMXiAdgu4nWEqRgC5HNFmNZf-q6L/view?usp=sharing)

I am working with Django 3.1, Python 3.8, Postgresql

Comment: Why is it a problem? If the user wants to make multiple records, that's their business surely? Exactly what issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: Does your insert and update views use GET method? (If it uses POST, the browser should warn the user about duplicating data)

Comment: You should use a POST reuest (or PUT, PATCH, DELETE) for requests with side-effects.

Comment: Definitely use POST - but for a better user experience, use the [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern

Comment: The truth is not a problem, of course it can record several records, but the user can be, as they say, get entangled or lost,
Example when I make a purchase I cannot go back and buy the same thing again, of course I can, but I have to do the process from 0, it is understood, thank you

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yfRxsdlqfnaDr3Dv1xfHyFVVcJGGmstT/view?usp=sharing